# Rails use case for validates_associated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, has-many

I've been reading about rails validations, and the `validates_associated` method validates all child records (not just new ones), whereas the default validation of a `has_many` association is to save new child records only.

Conceptually I understand this, but I'm trying to come up with a use case of why a child value would be invalid. For example, if a `Movie` `has_many` `Ratings`, why would I be editing a rating and not validating it?

Could someone provide an actual example of where `validates_associated` would be necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Lets take same example as you provided Movie has_many Ratings. If your going to save a movie along with ratings and if a rating has a validation error then the movie should not be saved. Using validates_associated will help this - movie will be saved only when its children are valid. Hope this helps you

Comment: That makes sense, but in thinking about how this would happen in an application - I wouldn't think you would be able to assign a non-existent rating to a movie (e.g. all ratings would be created ahead of time, so they are validated when they are saved).

Comment: wouldnt the rating have its own validatons run when its saved? how can you save the movie and create a rating at the same time? In my understanding rating will be created first then it will be linked to the movie. right?

Answer (score 0):

Consider `Rating` has a field named `score` which must be `>= 0` and `<= 5`.
In `rails console`:

```
>> m = Movie.first
=> #<Movie id: 1, name: "Lord of the Rings">

>> r = m.ratings.first
=> #<Rating id: 1, score: 5>

>> m.valid?
=> true

>> r.valid?
=> true

>> r.score = -1
=> -1

>> r.valid?
=> false
```

If you don't use `validates_associated`:

```
>> m.valid?
=> true
```

If you use `validates_associated`:

```
>> m.valid?
=> false

>> m.errors.messages
=> {:ratings => ["is invalid"]}
```

But if you don't use `validates_associated`, when you run `m.save`, only the movie record is updated, but not the associated ratings. So I don't see any harm if you don't use `validates_associated`.